# Slow custom SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sccm

I have created a custom SQL view to pull data from another view

The goal is to show application installation failures per computer

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT MachineName, COUNT(1) AS ErrorCount
FROM         dbo.vAppDeploymentErrorAssetDetails
WHERE     (ErrorCode <> 0)
GROUP BY MachineName
```

Currently this query takes several minutes to run, possibly because there is a huge amount of data in the source view, but it does not take long to run itself

I need to get this data to run in under 30 seconds for a dashboard display and have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how you can optimize this code without knowing what the underlying view is doing.

Comment: You need to show the definition of the View.  And probably the execution plan.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Using [Query analyzer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945(v=sql.80).aspx) You add one table each time and check performance. And when you get something slow, check for proper index.

Comment: `TOP (100) PERCENT` is pointless but *probably* not doing any harm.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Query Analyzer? I haven't seen that in a LONG time.

Comment: If SQL Server I would highly recommend [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) to view the execution plan. It's free and awesome.

Comment: @SeanLange what do you use?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza QA went away in sql 2005 and was replaced with SSMS. I was just surprised to see a link to QA. :)

Comment: I think the main issue here is that you have created a view that selects from a view. Nested views in sql server are a recipe for poor performance. Here are a couple of articles discussing the performance pitfalls of nested views. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ and http://www.scarydba.com/tag/nested-view/. There are plenty of others out there.

Comment: Interestingly I did not add the PERCENT item. This is a copy from what the view code shows now